# Bindings of a child WPF control are not updating when bound to parent control properties

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a UserControl (Pager1) that I have defined.  In this control, I have defined the property **TotalRecords**.  I have another UserControl (ListDisplay), which contains an instance of Pager1.  I am attempting to bind **TotalRecords** of Pager1 to the property **ParentTotalRecords** of ListDisplay.  I do not get any errors, but **TotalRecords** is never updated.

Can anyone explain to me why this is not working, and how I can get it to work?

Thanks.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.ListDisplay"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace">

<local:Pager1 x:Name="pgrPager"
    TotalRecords="{Binding ParentTotalRecords}" /> <!-- This binding does not update -->
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Is it "never updated" or is it "never set in the first place"? There is a huge difference between these two in terms of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a problem of change notifications? Are the proper interfaces implemented? ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx))

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.ListDisplay"
             x:Name="root"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace">

    <local:Pager1 x:Name="pgrPager"
                  TotalRecords="{Binding Path=ParentTotalRecords, ElementName=root}" />
</UserControl>
```

and of course, make sure ParentTotalRecords is a DependancyProperty and TotalRecords is also a DependencyProperty.

Comment: Dont need to be DP, just need to implement INotify